# php exec output is getting truncade truncated because of accents

Tags: php, exec, encode, diacritics, truncated

I'm building a website on a linux server which can provide some informations about mkv file using mkvmerge command line but i'm facing a big issue when using the command `$info = shell_exec("mkvmerge -J '".$chemin_fichier."'");`
when the output of the command line contains accents, the output is being truncated :

exptected output :

```
{
  "container": {
    "properties": {
      "is_providing_timestamps": true,
      "title": "Le Bel Été 2019"
    },
    "type": "Matroska"
  }
}
```

actual output :

```
{
  "container": {
    "properties": {
      "is_providing_timestamps": true,
      "title": "Le Bel
```

I did find on the web that we needed to modify the language of the environnement [using putenv() and setlocale() ] which i did but it didn t work. But i can define some variables using accents so this is quite strange.

anyway, when i run the same file on my computer using wamp server, or the same command line in my linux server terminal, i'm getting the correct output so i think the problem come from php(7.3) or apache(2.4).

do you have any idea ? Feel free to ask for extra details :)

Comment: you are showing a data structure which helps, but you are failing in showing source code. Im sure you are well aware that this is programming website. Some may say I should be "nicer" in saying this. The nice way would be where is your problem?

Comment: If the problem is on Windows - *On Windows, the underlying pipe is opened in text mode which can cause the function to fail for binary output. Consider to use popen() instead for such cases.* (from the manual on `shell_exec()`)

Comment: @GetSet there is no more code ... The only line involved is the one i wrote down in the introduction of the post i.e $info = shell_exec("mkvmerge -J '".$chemin_fichier."'").

Comment: @NigelRen my problem is on linux... But on windows, i have absolutely no problem running the exact same command :-)

Comment: Then seems it would be a `mkvmerge` issue? As the programmer (you) couldnt you rename the files to a suitable format that `mkvmerge` understands?

Comment: @GetSet as i mentionned earlier, when i use mkvmerge command on the terminal of my linux machine, i have no issue ! This really is a php problem unfortunately :-)

Comment: Does the command processor (mkvmerge) understand single quotes? Try double quotes as follows `$info = shell_exec("mkvmerge -J " . '"' . $chemin_fichier . '"');`

Comment: @GetSet yeah mkvmerge do understand single quotes because when i type the exact same command in my server terminal (which is a linux machine), i have the correct output !   By the way, the "title" proprieties is not linked to the file name :-).

Comment: ok i found out that the problem is comming from my linux machine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out !

actually, the language "fr_FR.utf8" does not work for accents and special characters while "en_US.utf8" seems to be the only solution.

The default language on my server was POSIX which does not allow accents neither.

to make things work, place the following lines in your php script

```
$locale = 'en_US.utf8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
```